# How do I find Uncle Ganga?

Tags: carto

In chapter 2 of Carto, I've been tasked with finding Uncle Ganga. There are some children who say Uncle Ganga is the forest, but I don't see him anywhere in the trees.

How do I find Uncle Ganga?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer courtesy of [Ind13.com](https://www.ind13.com/carto-walkthrough-chapter-2/)

> Monkar’s hint for finding Ganga is that he should be in the forest. We’ll have to build this forest ourselves, so enter the map and connect your current piece to a tile with a forest edge.
>
> Head towards the forest and you’ll find a boy tell you that he can hear Uncle Ganga’s voice in the forest. **Bring up your map and connect the forest pieces so that the three pieces surround an empty spot (with the forest edge facing the empty spot).**
>
> This will cause a new forest tile to appear. Head in there.
>
> [image]